# Extracting values From several raster .tif files to a .csv file using python

Tags: python, raster, geotiff-tiff, csv

I have multiple raster .tif files. I am using Python, and I want to extract cell's attribute values from all rasters based on the latitude and longitude similarity, and saved in a .csv file, the output should be formatted as follows:

lat lon value* value**

20  77  12     20

*denotes attribute value from raster 1

**denotes attribute value from raster 2

Can you please help me in this ?

Comment: Do you want to use pure Python or are there any libraries that you could use (rasterio, GDAL, etc.)?

Comment: What did you try, where did you search, because there are answers and solutions in GIS SE

Comment: I can use python libraries; it's not restricted to pure python. However I can't use Qgis or Arcgis

Comment: I can use python libraries; it's not restricted to pure python. However I can't use Qgis or Arcgis @Kersten

Comment: Do the rasters have the same location and dimensions?

Comment: Yes, same Projection and dimensions